# http-server-close option on NGINX?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, haproxy

Does NGINX has an option similar to HAProxy's `option http-server-close` option? I'm trying to migrate a codebase from HAProxy to NGINX, but can't find an equivalent functionality on NGINX. Thanks a lot.

Comment: And what should it do?

Comment: It's the flag that allows the server-facing connection to be closed after the end of the response is received, while the client-facing connection remains open.

Comment: That's default behavior. See proxy_set_header